# Changing QGIS attribute table appearance

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

How can I change the appearance of the attribute table in QGIS, so that I can view the cell's font an its size smaller in my computer's screen?

Comment: Please ask your question in English in order to allow all users to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at below code to change configuration. We copy a config file for column with for a particular layer. We choose to set for all columns a width of 250. By default, width = -1 (for auto size)

With this code, you can play to hide columns, change their orders, change their width, tell if they are a field column or an action column

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
copy_columns = []
attributeTableConfig = QgsAttributeTableConfig()
# Plaything you can use to revert the order of column if used
# for i in reversed(layer.attributeTableConfig().columns()):
for i in layer.attributeTableConfig().columns():
    colConfig = attributeTableConfig.ColumnConfig()
    colConfig.hidden = i.hidden
    colConfig.name = i.name # You may use this name to custom each col size depending of your knowledge of custom content in each column name
    colConfig.type = i.type
    colConfig.width = 250
    copy_columns.append(colConfig)

attributeTableConfig.setColumns(copy_columns)

layer.setAttributeTableConfig(attributeTableConfig)
```

**Old (only about fonts)**

You may use the following content in a `custom.qss` file and load it as a new theme using plugin "Load QSS - UI themes"

```
QgsAttributeTableView, QHeaderView {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

You may look at QSS reference at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html to learn more

Below an overview result before/after

[image: Default style]

[image: Style after QSS changes]

Comment: What about my cell's size?, Can I change it's size too with this plugin?

Comment: Updated answer with code (no need for the plugin except for fonts size, except if other people can recommend a better solution)