# Setting permanent minimum height and width of all cells in attribute table with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, dimensions, width

Let's assume there is an attribute table of a vector layer which was opened with <kbd>F6</kbd>, see image below

[image: input]

With the code below I could set the minimum height and width of all cells in the attribute table.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if 'QgsAttributeTableDialog' in d.objectName()]

if len(attrTables):
    attrTables[0].findChildren(QTableView)[0].resizeColumnsToContents()
    attrTables[0].findChildren(QTableView)[0].resizeRowsToContents()
```

[image: result_temp]

However it is only temporal. After closing and opening the table, the height of each cell does not remain, only the width is maintained.

[image: result_current]

How can I make it permanent in height?

---

**References:**

- [Adjusting attribute table view column width using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91451/how-to-adjust-qgis-attribute-table-view-column-width-using-python)

Comment: Have you seen the [`setAttributeTableConfig()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab91616c2e2e296fa97a3ab8bc0a36f7d) method of `QgsVectorLayer`? Perhaps this is the way to go. Unfortunately, I don't have time to look into it properly right now.

Comment: Thank you for a hint!

Comment: My other suggestion would be to attach your current code to the signal that is fired when an attribute table is opened. I can't easily see which signal that is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Conclusion

- It is impossible to apply permanent changes to cells' height. It seems like [`resizeRowsToContents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#resizeRowsToContents) works only partially. Because after closing the attribute table, rows won't preserve their dimension
- It is possible to adjust column width both via PyQt and PyQGIS

---

Indeed, as was mentioned in a comment by @Matt, there is a [`setAttributeTableConfig()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html) method of the [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) class:

> This is a container for configuration of the attribute table.
>
> The configuration is specific for one vector layer.

To get the width of a column one can try the [`attributeTableConfig()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aa327aa745c24b1254d5c0082d15f7a77) method.

> Returns the attribute table configuration object.
>
> This defines the appearance of the attribute table.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface 

layer = iface.activeLayer()

layer_attr_table_config = layer.attributeTableConfig()
columns = layer_attr_table_config.columns()

for column in columns:
    if not column.hidden:
        print(f"Column '{column.name}' : {column.width}")
```

Nevertheless, it will show [the default width](https://api.qgis.org/api/structQgsAttributeTableConfig_1_1ColumnConfig.html#a9707caf57a81f7f02d26a437acf20e49) which is `-1`.

```
Column 'osm_id' : -1
Column 'lastchange' : -1
Column 'code' : -1
Column 'fclass' : -1
Column 'geomtype' : -1
Column 'name' : -1
Column 'type' : -1
Column 'height' : -1
Column 'levels' : -1
```

More details can be found in [`QgsAttributeTableConfig`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html) class.

### To change the width of a single column

It utilizes the [`setColumnWidth()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html#adb48e1ece6d511066d33656c60cdc147) and [`setAttributeTableConfig()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab91616c2e2e296fa97a3ab8bc0a36f7d) methods

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def setting_one_column_width(layer_name: str, column_name: str, new_width: int):
    """
    Changes the width of a single column in the layer
    :param layer_name: name of the layer
    :param column_name: name of the target column
    :param new_width: new column width in pixels
    """
    
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    column_index = layer.fields().indexOf(column_name)

    layer_attr_table_config = layer.attributeTableConfig()
    layer_attr_table_config.setColumnWidth(column_index, new_width)
    
    layer.setAttributeTableConfig(layer_attr_table_config)

    return

setting_one_column_width('gis_osm_buildings', 'osm_id', 100)
```

### To change the width of all columns

Based on [@ThomasG77's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389173/99589). It uses the [`setColumns()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html#a8a018be39a06e7caa2202adf868daae7) and [`setAttributeTableConfig()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab91616c2e2e296fa97a3ab8bc0a36f7d) methods

```py
from qgis.core import QgsAttributeTableConfig, QgsProject

def setting_all_columns_widths(layer_name: str, new_width: int) -> None:
    """
    Changes widths of all columns in the layer
    :param layer_name: name of the layer
    :param new_width: new column width in pixels
    """
    
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    layer_attr_table_config = layer.attributeTableConfig()
    columns_config = layer_attr_table_config.columns()

    new_columns_config = []
    new_layer_attr_table_config = QgsAttributeTableConfig()

    for column in columns_config:
        new_column = layer_attr_table_config.ColumnConfig()
        new_column.hidden = column.hidden
        new_column.name = column.name
        new_column.type = column.type
        new_column.width = new_width
        new_columns_config.append(new_column)

    new_layer_attr_table_config.setColumns(new_columns_config)

    layer.setAttributeTableConfig(new_layer_attr_table_config)

    return

setting_all_columns_widths('gis_osm_buildings', 100)
```

Keep in mind, that changes will be noticeable after closing and opening again the attribute table.

However, there are also several incompleteness in the above approaches:

1. autosize functionality comes from [PyQt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/)
2. it does not shrink rows, only columns

### To autosize the width of all columns

Partially overlaps with [@Joseph's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/299896/99589) and [@MatthiasKuhn's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91453/99589) answers. It applies the [`resizeColumnsToContents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#resizeColumnsToContents) method from the [`QTableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html) class.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

def autosize_all_columns_widths(layer_name: str) -> None:
    """
    Autosizes widths of all columns in the layer
    :param layer_name: name of the layer
    """

    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
    attribute_table_widgets = [widget for widget in all_widgets if "AttributeTable" in widget.objectName()]

    if len(attribute_table_widgets) == 0:
        iface.showAttributeTable(layer)
        all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
        attribute_table_widgets = [widget for widget in all_widgets if "AttributeTable" in widget.objectName()]

    for widget in attribute_table_widgets:
        if not widget.isWindow():
            if layer.name() in widget.objectName():
                table_view = widget.findChildren(QTableView)[0]
                table_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
                # table_view.resizeRowsToContents()
                widget.close()

    return

autosize_all_columns_widths('gis_osm_buildings')
```

---

**References:**

- [Changing QGIS attribute table appearance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389161/changing-qgis-attribute-table-appearance)
- [Opening attribute table using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68332/opening-attribute-table-using-pyqgis)
- [How to show the attribute table inside the dialogue of a custom plugin with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425009/how-to-show-the-attribute-table-inside-the-dialogue-of-a-custom-plugin-with-qgis)