# Editing width of drop down field list in the QGIS Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, dropdownlist, width

Can I change the width of the drop-down field (attribute) list in the attribute table that is used for editing, i.e. the highlighted drop-down in the image below with the value `"ID"`? The list is so narrow I can't see field names easily.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: I have tried this again today and yours (Taras) and Louis's solutions now both work. I think there must have been some sort of corruption in my project file - before trying today I had recreated the project. Mnay thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a PyQGIS solution I can suggest. Honestly, it was tricky, and not straightforward.

The thing you are looking for is the [`QFrame`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qframe.html) hidden under `AttributeTable / mUpdateExpressionBox / mFieldCombo`. It has a corresponding method for that called [`setFixedWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth).

Let's assume there is a point layer with an opened attribute table in edited mode, see the below:

[image: input]

The default width of [this drop-down list](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-quick-field-calculation-bar) is 100, possible to see by means of the [`width()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#width-prop) method.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame

# accessing layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points_in_polygon")[0]

# looking for the attribute table widget
all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
attribute_table_widgets = [widget for widget in all_widgets if "AttributeTable" in widget.objectName() and layer.name() in widget.objectName()]

# if layer has no opened attribute table, open it
if len(attribute_table_widgets) == 0:
    iface.showAttributeTable(layer)
    all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
    attribute_table_widgets = [widget for widget in all_widgets if "AttributeTable" in widget.objectName() and layer.name() in widget.objectName()]

# finding attribute table widget that matches layer name 
for widget in attribute_table_widgets:
    # looping over elements of the layer's attribute table
    for elem1 in widget.children():
        if elem1.objectName() == 'mUpdateExpressionBox':
            for elem2 in elem1.children():
                if elem2.objectName() == 'mFieldCombo':
                    for elem3 in elem2.children():
                        if isinstance(elem3, QFrame):
                            # here change to desired width value
                            elem3.setFixedWidth(500)
```

Change the name of your input layer. Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like this:

[image: result]

Now the new width is 500.

This solution will work as long as you keep your attribute table open, does not matter if it will be edited multiple times.

Perhaps, there is more easier way to exist.

P.S. I would appreciate it if someone could try this code.

---

**References:**

- [Setting permanent minimum height and width of all cells in attribute table with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431717/setting-permanent-minimum-height-and-width-of-all-cells-in-attribute-table-with)

Comment: That is one very ugly for loop ... 
Also doesn't work for me on 3.22.11

Comment: Fully agree with you :) you can suggest a better one anytime

Comment: I was working on it, its coming.

Comment: does your script work as is for you? because I had to change `if not widget.isWindow():` to `if widget.isWindow():` for it to work for me but it might be something version dependant for all I know

Comment: The attribute table is a `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QDialog` class. I suppose we can omit it. Because ["Returns true if the widget is an independent window, otherwise returns false."](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#isWindow).

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. No error, but nothing happens

Comment: I updated this answer also so it opens the attribute table even if there is an attribute table of another layer already open

Comment: I tried this too, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

To complement @Taras's answer with a simpler python code (changed with edit):

```py
# imports
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame

# accessing layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points_in_polygon")[0]

# looking for the attribute table widget
all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
attribute_table_widgets = [
    widget for widget in all_widgets 
    if "AttributeTable" in widget.objectName()
    and layer.id() in widget.objectName()
]

# if layer has no opened attribute table, open it
if len(attribute_table_widgets) == 0:
    iface.showAttributeTable(layer)
    all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
    attribute_table_widgets = [
        widget 
        for widget in all_widgets 
        if "AttributeTable" in widget.objectName()
        and layer.id() in widget.objectName()
    ]

# finding attribute table widget that matches layer name 
for widget in attribute_table_widgets:
    # get the right combo box of the layer's attribute table
    update_expression_box = widget.findChild(QFrame, "mUpdateExpressionBox")
    combo_box = update_expression_box.findChild(QComboBox, "mFieldCombo")
    
    # change the width of the entire combo box
    combo_box.setFixedWidth(500)
    
    # or to only change the width of the drop-down list (same as @Taras)
    # drop_down_list = combo_box.findChild(QFrame, "")
    # drop_down_list.setFixedWidth(500)
```

EDIT:

The name of the layer cannot contain "-" (or be different than the source name of the layer) otherwise the condition `layer.name() in widget.objectName()` will fail.

Because it check that the layer name is in the object name of the QgsAttributeTableDialog object which is built like so:
"QgsAttributeTableDialog/@layer_id". The problem being that "-" cannot exist in the `@layer_id`. Meaning that "-" in the layer name are converted to "_" in the layer id.

The solution being that using `layer.id()` will work more reliably than `layer.name()`

Comment: Exactly! I was thinking about the [`findChild`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QObject.findChild) or [`findChildren`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QObject.findChildren) method

Comment: I though about directly using `findChildren` which does recursive search but there are two `QComboBox` with name "mFieldCombo" with different intermediary parents making it just simpler to just do it in two steps

Comment: A great adding with `combo_box.setFixedWidth(500)` :)

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. No error, but nothing happens

Comment: @Oisin Edited: It didn't work right when there were another attribute table open

Comment: I do appreciate your help, and it seems to be closer: now all QGIS windows seem to repaint, but still no change to the combo_box width.

Comment: ...and a second instance of the attribute table opens

Comment: can you edit your question with a screen of your legend and which layer are you tried to use this on please?

Comment: Sure. But 'Legend' - I do not understand, is this not layout item. The attribte table I have open is for layer 'tree-pt'. I did edit your code so that layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("tree-pt")[0] .

Comment: OP edited with new image

Comment: It really should work even with the attribute table docked to the main window. What is your QGIS version? The oldest version I could try was the 3.16.11 and it worked fine up to 3.40.0. If you can, try installing a newer version of QGIS if yours is a bit old.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149891/discussion-between-oisin-and-louis-cottereau).

Comment: See discussion for further comment

Comment: @Louis Now working - I think the Project was corrupted. I recreated it and it is now working. Thanks for all your help.